# Semantic meaning of writing functions

Tags: javascript, semantics

We can write functions in 2 ways:

```
var v1 = m1('hello'); // error
var v2 = m2('hello'); // OK

var m1 = function(param){ 
    // ... 
    return param; 
}

function m2(param){
    // ...
    return param;
}

var v1 = m1('hello'); // OK
var v2 = m2('hello'); // OK
```

As I know there is only one difference - **time of creation**:
`m2` in compilation time, so we can use it 'before' declaration - like in my case.
`m1` in assignment time (code goes line by line) and we cannot use it before.

Is one more efficient for memory or performance?
In which case is one way more semantic, in which case second?
Is here next difference?
When we should use first and when second one?

.

// **edit** really primitive perf test - **same results**
// http://jsperf.com/performance-function-writing-way

Comment: Try making a test on jsperf.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: There are no "compilation time" in JavaScript! You create `m2()` using function declaration, so it is hoisted to the top of the parent function or, in your case, the whole script.

Comment: @ondrek: They both create a function, so they perform the same. Sorry I didn't say that earlier. I just meant create a jsperf for creating the functions, not executing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var m1 = function(param){ 
    // ... 
    return param; 
}

it may make more sense when you consider that a function is an object, and we're just assigning a name to the object.  Think of it as saying var m1=[1,2,3];  The content of functions declared this way is also compiled.

When assigning a function like this, we are not restricted to an unnamed function, and I can refer to the function by the name or by the variable.

for more info you must look into this article...

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The name of the following function is `m1`. It is stored in the current scope as `m1`. It is accessible everywhere in this scope regardless of code order.

```
function m1(){}
```

The following function has no name. It is stored in the current scope as `m2`. It is accessible only in lines after it.

```
var m2 = function(){}
```

You can also assign named functions to other variables:

```
var m1 = m2;
function m2(){}
var m3 = function m4(){};
var m5 = function(){};
```

In Firefox's console:

```
>>> m1
m2()

>>> m2
m2()

>>> m3
m4()

>>> m4
ReferenceError: m4 is not defined

>>> m5
function()
```

Comment: And for personal preference, I almost always use the first method so I can order function definitions from high-level to low-level.

Answer (score 1):

If you only wish to have a function avaliable by specific name, the minimum way is to write without assignment. Just because you don't need to perform an extra action and write extra code, you just need to have a function you can call.

A way with assignment you've written is an **example of using an anonymous function**, and it's not practically the case that *needs* an anonymous function. One example use of this feature is that you can pass actions to certain functions as arguments. Take a look at [this page of jQuery docs on `hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). This function accepts two arguments: the length of animation and the action to do after it's complete. You may not need that action anywhere else, so why make another identifier and clutter your namespace? There might be reasons, but these are beyond the scope of this question.

JS syntax allows both, but it's a side effect of having anonymous functions avaliable in JS.

So it's a matter of choice and habits.